# Socket IO Node Angular Chat Service

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I'm posting about a situation i ran into when implementing a guide I found online: https://codingblast.com/chat-application-angular-socket-io/

It was working well. I was able to connect to the node server when going to the right component on my website. A lot of the code I'm going to post is very similar to what I found on the website.

Also I got to the point where I was able to see "started on port : 3000" and "user connected" This works. But I can't seem to send messages to the server.

Here is the file where I think the problem is happening:

**index.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let http = require('http');
let server = http.Server(app);

let socketIO = require('socket.io');
let io = socketIO(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

**chat.componenet.html**

```
<div class="main-container--chat">
  <div class="message-box-container">
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
      {{message}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="chat-input">
    <input [(ngModel)]="message" (keyup)="$event.keyCode == 13 && sendMessage()"/>
    <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chat.component.ts**

```
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  messages: string[] = [];

  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chatService
      .getMessages()
      .subscribe((message: string) => {
        this.messages.push(message);
      });
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
    this.message = '';
  }
}
```

and finally **chatService.service.ts**

```
 export class ChatService {
      private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
      private socket;

      constructor() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
      }

      public sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit('new-message', message);
      }

      public getMessages = () => {
        return 

    Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
        observer.next(message);
      });
        });
      }
    }
```

I did my best to keep the posted code specific. I hope it's not too much to glare at. Especially on a Friday.

But again, when running index.js via Node. I am able to view that a "user connected" and that port:3000 started. But, when I send a message, the server never receives it. Also when I try to console.log("somethign random"); inside:

```
  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

I don't see that random console log message appear. I don't think my naming is incorrect for new-message.

I'm new to this so I hope it's not something obvious. I'd really appreciate any help.

Edit: restarted server and got the logging to work. But all code staying the same and adding

```
io.emit(message);
```

to

```
  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

I'm still not getting the messages on the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to additionally emit/broadcast the `new-message` event with the payload of the string message on the server using `emit` on `io`, specifically `io.emit('new-message', message)`, within the socket `socket.on('new-message', (message) => { })`. This way the client connected to this socket can receive the `new-message` events within the observable stream.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    io.emit('new-message', message); // emit event
  });
});
```

You shouldn't need to make any changes to your Angular/client code. Just remember to implement some sort of tear down of the observable using something along the lines of `complete()` within the body of `complete()` or terminating/filtering operators such as [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html). Otherwise you can/will have potential memory leaks.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Wow, sorry about the late response. But, it worked!

Thank you so much. And thank you for explaining it. So if I wanted multiple chat rooms, would I need a new port for each room?

Comment: I think that's correct. But I do have another question: using the variable "io" which is of type socketIO, when using the "on" function, does the first parameter take arbitrary values? I'm having a little bit of troubling finding documentation specifically on that function

Comment: You can use rooms/namespaces instead of new sockets. Check out this documentation https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: The first argument isn’t arbitrary. It’s the string event identifier. It would need to effectively match across the server and client to emit and receive messages.

Comment: gotcha yes, I'm just noticing that now. Thank you very much again. That was kind of the key thing to getting me connected

Comment: This is a very powerful API. Is there anything better than socket.io? What are the drawbacks?